# how to run easy_install using a particular python version

Tags: python, easy-install, orange

I have 3 python versions, I want to easy_install Orange using the second version. How can I do this?

Unnecessary info:

1. 2.1 in /usr/bin/python
2. 2.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
3. 3.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin/python

Answer:
Ok found it [here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#multiple-python-versions) (http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#multiple-python-versions),

"Also, if you're working with Python version 2.4 or higher, you can run Python with -m easy_install to run that particular Python version's easy_install command"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

easy_install is usually/always installed *per Python version*. So you run the related version of easy_install installed for your particular Python version/interpreter you want to use here.

Comment: It would help if you would've posted an example command to specify this flag.

Answer (score 51):

Just so the answer is easy to find:

Using "Python-version" with the m-parameter and easy_install afterwards does the trick.

Example:

```
python2.7 -m easy_install https://bitbucket.org/james_taylor/bx-python/get/tip.tar.bz2
```

Comment: `python3 -m easy_install mountain_tapir` -> `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named easy_install`

Answer (score 5):

Say your python version is 3.5. Then you can use the command `easy_install-3.5` followed by the name of the module you are willing to download/install. See documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#multiple-python-versions).

Comment: I did not DV, but I do not think it is always true that you will neccessarily have an easy_install-3.5 or easy_install-X for a particular version of easy_install.

Answer (score 2):

From the doc, besides the reported option

```
python2.7 -m easy_install
```

there is also:

if you install EasyInstall for both Python 2.3 and 2.4, you can use the easy_install-2.3 or easy_install-2.4 scripts to install packages for Python 2.3 or 2.4