# Easy_install keeps installing the package to an outdated version of python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, networkx

[Using Mac OSX 10.6.8]

i'm tryring to install networkx to python 2.7, but it keeps trying to install it to version 2.6 (which in uninstalled when i upgraded to 2.7)

i tried easy_install for an unspecified version, and it got the 2.6 version

command:

easy_install networkx

output

```
Searching for networkx
Best match: networkx 1.7
Processing networkx-1.7-py2.6.egg
Removing networkx 1.7 from easy-install.pth file
Adding networkx 1.7 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/networkx-1.7-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for networkx
Finished processing dependencies for networkx
smms-baldrick:20121205_coif kirstin$
```

i tried downloading the python 2.7 version and installing it directly, but it still went to the library for 2.6

command:

easy_install http://networkx.lanl.gov/download/networkx/networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg

output

```
Downloading http://networkx.lanl.gov/download/networkx/networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg
Processing networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg
removing '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg
Extracting networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg to /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
networkx 1.7 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for networkx==1.7
Finished processing dependencies for networkx==1.7
```

Comment: Long shot, but what is your default Python version on your system? My best/only guess is that you are running `easy_install with Python 2.6, which is installing it in the way that 2.6 needs to. Have you tried calling it with 2.7 directly?

Comment: which OS you are using? check the PATH Environment variable and ensure the python27 installation exists in path instead python26

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611730/how-to-run-easy-install-using-a-particular-python-version

Comment: Thanks, i've re-installed setuptools 0.6c11 for python 2.7, but the problem seems to still be happening.

Comment: i also tried echo $PATH and there's nothing on there that looks like python 2.6

Comment: What do you need from python2.7 that is not present in python2.6 and that you couldn't obtain from python3?

Comment: I've already uninstalled 2.6 and can't find a simple way to reinstall it. And other people from my lab write scripts (including this one that needs networx) in python 2, so python 3 won't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

In Unix variants easy_install also installs a suffixed link, so there should be an easy_install-2.7 . In general, it might be a good idea for you to know where exactly you have installed your new Python, and use that knowledge to install setup-tools, and then to use easy_install. For example:

```
 $ cd to/my/setuptools/
 $ sudo /my/new/python2.7 setup.py install
```

and afterwards

```
  $ /my/new/easy_install-2.7 networkx
```

And then you can create a set of symbolic links. Also, because Mac uses python internally, it might be a good idea to not mess with the default python installation, and instead use your own with something like [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) (which would automate the installation of setuptools).

Comment: Python is installed in the Applications folder of my Mac, and python 2.7 is the default python, but the easy_install for 2.6 seems to still be the default (i'm regretting upgrading to 2.7)

Comment: easy_install-2.7 wasn't recognised as a command. I managed to install this package with "python -m easy_install networkx", which called easy-install for my default python installation] but i could do with a more long term solution to change my default version of easy-install?

Comment: @Renee: You should never try to upgrade the system python. Always install other versions of Python in separate installs.

Answer (score 2):

You install easy_install for a particular installation of Python. That easy_install will then install into the Python installation for which easy_install is installed.

If you want to use easy_install to install packages into another Python installation, the first thing you must do is to instal easy_install in that Python installation. Then you can use that easy_install to install packages.

You might also want to use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) instead.

See also: [Newbie hint on installing Python and it’s modules and packages.](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/)

Comment: Thanks, i've re-installed setuptools 0.6c11 for python 2.7, but the problem seems to still be happening. Is it still using an old version of easy_install (the instructions mentioned removing old stuff for windows, but i'm using Mac OSX and it just said to install new version for that)

Comment: @Renee: So don't use the old version of easy_install. Use the new version. Just specify the path to the easy_install you want to use. Same thing with Python. Or pip. Or any other of these tools.

Answer (score 1):

i managed to install this package with

```
python -m easy_install networkx
```

from [how to run easy_install using a particular python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611730/how-to-run-easy-install-using-a-particular-python-version)

[which called easy-install for my default python installation]

but i could do with a more long term solution to change my default version of easy-install

Comment: You can just locate the easy_install for version 2.7 and sym-link it. But heed the advice of people here: do not mess with the default Python, I have taken quite a few Macs to the repair-shop just because of that.